# Can IntelliJ IDEA Replace in Path Preview the CHANGED text

Tags: intellij-idea

When using IntelliJ IDEA's Replace in Path the preview panel shows the text occurrences that **will** be changed as they are now. Is there any way to preview what the text will be **after** the change?

eg In the following I am changing "BEFORE" to "AFTER" and I would like to be able to see the line of code showing *FIELD = "AFTER"* **before** I commit to the refactor. Not a big deal for simple text but I think this is quite a shortcoming when using regular expressions and back-references to captured groups.

[image: Replace in Path Preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of IntelliJ IDEA 2016.2, only single-file replace actions support showing replacement preview. Multi-file find & replace, as well as refactorings, only support showing the list of locations that are going to be changed, but not the state after the operation.

Comment: OK thanks. I'll mark this as the answer. I've since come to the same conclusion and eventually found a Jetbrains feature request asking for this  option. Perhaps when you have a spare 5 minutes ;-) ... https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-87846